# Hive - Group by issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am doing a group by in Hive based on 2 fields (A and B). But it is not showing one aggregated value for every combination of A and B.

It is showing multiple values like

A B 1
A B 4
etc.

Is it because the number of reducers are more than 1. How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Will it work fine if I set number of reducers as 1?

Comment: show you database schema and query plz

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have met a similar problem,In my HQL,I use `insert overwrite directory '$HQL_OUT_PATH'` to overwrite the output.But It seems to be unstable which result in repeat items.You may clean the output path before the HQL and see if the output turn out to be right.